# JS: Object value depending on regEx match

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, reactjs

There are some objects in an array like this:

```
const result = [
  {
    "_id": "Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ",
    "title": "Something",
    "synonyms": [ "Anything", "else" ]
  },
  { ... }
]
```

I do get this result by performing this:

```
Content.find({
  $or: [
    { title: { $regex: new RegExp(term, 'i') } },
    { synonyms: { $regex: new RegExp(term, 'i') } }
  ]
}).toArray()
```

As you can see, I'm searching for title (string) or synonym (array) elements by a given search term.
So searching for `some` or `any` will give me the first document as my result.

In my component I do the output of the data like this:

```
render () {
  return result.map((link, index) => {
    return <Dropdown.Item
      text={link.title}
      key={index}
    />
  })
}
```

But right now I do get the output `Something` for the dropdown item if I'm searching for `any` (term). For the user this doesn't make sense.

Of course `any` should give me the output `Anything` and `some` should give me the output `Something`.
In this example you can also search for `thing` and I would expect two output elements (of one single result document): `Anything` and `Something`.

I'm not quite sure how to modify the code to get this result. I think the best place to modify should be the react component (output) - not the server request result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could issue two separate queries on the server side to maintain clearly which part of your document was matched. This would ensure that for the doc which matches using synonyms was not used to return title.

```
const matchingTitles = Content.find(
    { title: { $regex: new RegExp(term, 'i') } }
}, {title: 1} ).toArray().map(x => x.title);

const matchingSynonyms = Content.find(
    { synonyms: { $regex: new RegExp(term, 'i') } }
}, {synonyms: 1} ).toArray().map(x => x.synonyms).reduce((x, y) => x.concat(y), []);

return Array.from(new Set([...matchingTitles, ...matchingSynonyms]));
```

I fetch the strings separately using two queries and then take the set union of them.

And on client side you could use these strings directly to display the search result.